# client URL for self hosted devpi?

Tags: pip, pypi, twine, devpi, pypiserver

I am running [this](https://github.com/scrapinghub/docker-devpi) devpi docker container

as per instruction I have setup password in the environment variable DEVPI_PASSWORD to devpi then

I have setup ~/.pypirc file

```
[devpi]
repository:http://127.0.0.1:3141/root/pypi
username:root
password:devpi
```

but on trying to upload (to update it as it contains the old version of my package )the python package I get the error

```
$ twine upload -r devpi dist/*.tar.gz
Uploading distributions to http://127.0.0.1:3141/root/pypi
Uploading maildiff-1.3.0.tar.gz
100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 16.4k/16.4k [00:00<00:00, 667kB/s]
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://127.0.0.1:3141/root/pypi
```

so what should be the client URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/root/pypi` is a read-only proxy link to the PyPI repo at https://pypi.org. Its purpose is to install packages when they are not available on your local `devpi` instance. To upload packages to the local instance, you need to create a non-root user and an index first. On your host, start the container and (assuming the port mapping from container to host worked) issue:

```bash
$ devpi use http://127.0.0.1:3141
$ devpi login root                         # by default, only root can create new users
$ devpi user -c me password=mypass         # create new user
$ devpi login me                           # relogin as the new user
$ devpi index -c myindex bases=/root/pypi  # create new index
```

If you get the error `devpi: command not found`, stop the container and install `devpi-client` on your host:

```
$ pip install devpi-client
```

Now you have an index `http://127.0.0.1:3141/me/myindex` you can upload to. The configuration in `.pypirc` changes to:

```
[devpi]
repository:http://127.0.0.1:3141/me/myindex
username:me
password:mypass
```

Installing from the index will work by passing the index url to `pip`:

```
$ pip install maildiff --extra-index-url=http://127.0.0.1:3141/me/myindex
```

Comment: well, I am running via a container so I entered the container using `docker exec -it [container-id] bash` and ran the commands you mentioned: `root@efeb7f50c961:/# devpi login root
password for user root: ` and I got the following error in red: `could not connect to None:
Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?` then I tried `devpi user -c me  password=mypass` which gave error in red `could not connect to '/me':
Invalid URL '/me': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///me?` do I need to set something ?

Comment: You should do it outside of the container. Install `devpi-client` on your host, start the container and invoke the commands.

Comment: while trying to install devpi-client on host machine I get this error : `Collecting virtualenv>=1.11.2 (from tox!=3.0.0rc1,>=1.7.1->devpi-client)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=3141): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /root/pypi/+f/2ce/32cd126117ce2/virtualenv-16.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` and it is not going any further

Comment: some how it managed to go through and devpi client did got installed, however I still get the same error if I try `devpi user -c me password=mypass`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention the `devpi use`, it must be run once before you start connecting to the server. I updated the answer.

Comment: I also mentioned the installation of `devpi-client` on the host, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @hoefing : I figured out to `devpi use 127.0.0.1:3141/`  how I cannot open the url `127.0.0.1:3141/san/pypi/+simple` like I can open `127.0.0.1:3141/root/pypi/+simple`

Comment: What do you mean with "open"? What is the error message you get?

Comment: I was thriving to accomplish this today while working in office, even though we have devpi server setup in office no body fully knows or take advantage to full potential.

Comment: Yepp, it's a cool stuff. We started using `devpi` three or four years ago, have now three servers running (master + two replicas) and so far we did survive every PyPI blackout, also the simplicity of writing extensions for the server and client is astonishing.